# Программная распаковка sfx rar архива

Tags: c#, visual-c++

Доброго времени суток!

Есть некоторые архивы формата rar. Необходимо научить программу распаковывать их. Есть ли какой бесплатный или стоящих не больших денег модуль, который будет использоваться в коммерческом продукте и может программно осуществлять распаковку самораспаковывающихся архивов.

Зыж rar, потому, что нужно паковать альтернативные потоки данных ntfs.
Готов поменять архиватор, если он будет тоже потоки запаковывать вместе с файлом. На сколько мне известно, zip, 7zip, cab этого не поддерживают.

Ззыж самораспаковывающийся потому что предполагается распаковка архивов также пользователем. Используется модуль guisfx, с использованием диалога выбора каталога для распаковки. Про параметр silense=1 знаю, неподходит потому, что можно задать только на стадии добавления sfx модуля, что не возможно сделать на пользовательской стороне.

Заранее спасибо за вашу помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Библиотека UnRAR.dll

Взять можно [отсюда](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_add.htm)

Прямая ссылка на [архив с библиотекой UnRAR.dll](http://www.rarlab.com/rar/UnRARDLL.exe)

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Там есть исходный код, попытаюсь внедрить его, чтобы обойтись без дополнительного модуля...

Comment: Да, все отлично заработало. Исходник скомпилили в lib. Теперь можно прекрасно его использовать в любом проекте. Осталось самое малое, уточнить лицензионное соглашение =)

Comment: хм... ну с лицензией я затрудняюсь помочь. Попробуйте написать сюда http://www.rarlab.com/feedback.htm